# if statement issues with change

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

i am want to check dynamic value and variables that is **Yes** or **No**:

```js
jQuery("select.super-attribute-select").change(function() {
  //console.log("New Product ID: " + this.value);
  var option_id11 = "Yes";
  var option_id12 = "No";
  var selectedvalue = this.value;

  //var optionvalue = "option_id"+selectedvalue;

  if ("option_id" + selectedvalue === "Yes") {
    console.log('hide');
  } else if ("option_id" + selectedvalue === "No") {
    console.log('show');
  } else {
    console.log('Nothing');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="super_attribute[161]" data-selector="super_attribute[161]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute161" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">
  <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
  <option value="11">REFURB</option>
  <option value="12">NEW</option>
</select>
```

but its always show **Nothing** in console. please help

Comment: how can any value `+ "option_id"` ever equal to 'yes' or `no` ?

Comment: That's becaseu "option_id11/12" will never equal "Yes" nor "No".

Comment: `"option_id"+selectedvalue` what do you think this line is doing? You are comparing **two strings**, are you aware of that?

Comment: may be you want `option_id11+selectedvalue` not sure

Comment: What you want to achieve here?

Comment: You are comparing two strings which already will never return true.

Comment: Try using eval("option_id"+selectedvalue)

Comment: Why not simply do `if(selectedvalue==='11') {...}`?

Comment: @TiiJ7 11, 12 are dynamic from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call variables using strings representing the name of that variable. Try creating an object to specify the values instead:

```
jQuery("select.super-attribute-select").change(function() {
       //console.log("New Product ID: " + this.value);

        var options = {
          option_id11: "Yes",
          option_id12: "No"
        }

        var selectedvalue = this.value;

        var selectedOptionValue = options["option_id"+selectedvalue];

        if (selectedOptionValue === "Yes") {
            console.log('hide');
        } else if (selectedOptionValue === "No") {
            console.log('show');
        } else {
            console.log('Nothing');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("select.super-attribute-select").change(function() {
   var data = {
     option_id11:"Yes",
     option_id12:"No"
   }
   var selectedvalue = this.value;
   if (data["option_id"+selectedvalue] === "Yes") {
      console.log('hide');
   } else if (data["option_id"+selectedvalue] === "No") {
      console.log('show');
   } else {
      console.log('Nothing');
   }

});
```